# Could you please explain the following js code? I dont understand the foreach loop here

Tags: javascript

I dont understand the following foreach loop here. Could you please explain?

```
var fs = require("fs");
console.log("Going to read directory /tmp");
fs.readdir("/tmp/", function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    files.forEach(function(file) {
        console.log(file);

    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: files is assumed to a list/array/collection of some sort, and every item in that collection will be written to the console...

Answer (score 0):

According to the fs documentation:

Asynchronous readdir(3). Reads the contents of a directory. The callback gets two arguments (err, files) where files is an array of the names of the files in the directory excluding '.' and '..'.

So, you have a list of the files that are from the specified directory.

Doc here: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback

Answer (score 0):

`files` is collection object here which may contain multiple items. The `forEach` loop traverses each item of `files` collection and you can access each item (file) inside `forEach` via `function(file) {}`

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` takes every item of `files` array, and executes the function for every item, and passes this item itself into the function as a parameter. All code inside the function:

```
files.forEach(function(file) {
  console.log(file);
});
```

will be executed for every array item (it works similar to regular `for` loop).

For mor info about `forEach`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

It is something like below :

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
a.forEach(function(entry) {
 console.log(entry);
});
```

So, for example if files contains array of name of files than each will be printed in browser console.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
files.forEach(function(file) {
    console.log(file);
});
```

does exactly the same of:

```
for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
    console.log(files[i]);
}
```